# Checking character encoding within Oracle, java and Linux OS

Tags: java, linux, oracle, encoding

I have an application that processes some data and loads it into the database. The incoming data is recieved in the following format:

```
aaaaaaa aaaa® aaaaaaa
```

After running the java process to load the data, it shows as shown below in the database:

aaaaaaa aaaa�� aaaaaaa

I run the same process using the same file on a test server and it is appearing correctly on the test server. I need to compare the two servers to work out what the difference is
in the encoding of the servers.

How do i change the configured encoding for the following:

```
The oracle database (Oracle 11g)
The linux operating system
The JDK (version 1.6)
```

Thanks

Comment: check the oracle character set by running `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');` first. are they different or the same? also are you inserting into a varchar2/clob or nvarchar2/nclob? changing a character set of an existing db is shown here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm#g1011430.

Comment: Running that query returns the same character set for both databases.

Comment: I insert in both clobs and varchars and the issue exists in both

Comment: Can you show some of the java code ?